# Ria services - Beta 2009 Perview- max number of CRUD Opt per service

Tags: c#, silverlight, ria

I have more than 78 POCO entities and I want to put all CRUD operation in single service.

VS 2008 doesn't compile I have checked all source file :

> error :DomainOperation Entity does not represent a Query of operation so it must not return a value.

Are there some **limitations** in number of Entities exposed by one single service in RIA BETA (2009 perview) ?